# Using a static variable to break out of recursion

Tags: java, recursion, static-variables

Aim: Find if a tree is a balanced binary tree.

I have implemented a program that does work, but wanted to make it more efficient by preventing unnecessary recursion. To do this I am using a static variable, that is set when even a single condition is evaluated to false, so that every other recursive call returns, before making any of their own recursive calls.

```
static int shouldIExit=0;
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if(root==null){
        return true;
    }
    if(shouldIExit==1 || Math.abs(height(root.left)-height(root.right))>1){
        height(root.right))>1: "+ (Math.abs(height(root.left)-height(root.right))>1) ) ;
        shouldIExit=1;
        return false;
    }
    else{
     return (isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right) );   
    }
}
```

The problem is that the static variable is somehow being set even when no condition causes it to do so. i.e., shouldIExit is set to 1 even when the if condition corresponding to it, does not evaluate to true.

Is this me not understanding how static variables work?

Comment: Try to remove `shouldIExit`

Comment: Without seeing your tree node and invoking code it's hard to see what is going on. But in this case you do not need a static variable. An instance variable (a variable that exists on class level once per object) is sufficient. A static variable exists once per entire class. Do you have multiple objects of the same class? If one of them alters the value it will change everywhere else as well.

Comment: @user7294900 I want to break out of all recursive calls as soon as one recursive call evaluates to false. The only way I thought that one recursive call can 'talk' to the other ones is by using static variables. I'm open to alternatives

Comment: in your example shouldIExit doesnt improve performance, actually it does nothing

Comment: @Kilian I am not creating any objects here. I guess i'm using static variables in a non-conventional way. The idea is to have a glolbal variable such that one recursive call can 'broadcast' to all the others saying **'Hey, I found a case where this evaluates to false, so stop whatever you are doing and return'.** And for this, i want to use a static variable

Comment: you understand how static works, but what you are not aware about is how depth first traversal works and and how call stack works in recursion. get a sample tree and go simulate your code flow,then you will understand this static variable does nothing. FYI ,&& operator will short circuit the evaluation.

Comment: Thanks everyone! Got confused with the recursive calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a `static` variable. It's usually bad practice to use non-local variables (either `static` or instance variables) in a recursive method.

```
public boolean isBalanced(TreeNode root) {
    if(root==null) {
        return true;
    }
    if(Math.abs(height(root.left)-height(root.right))>1) {
        return false;
    } else{
     return (isBalanced(root.left) && isBalanced(root.right) );
    }
}
```

You could save some work if you combine the logic of `height` and `isBalanced`. I believe something like this should work:

```
public boolean isBalanced (TreeNode root) {
    return balancedHeight(root) >= 0;
}

public int balancedHeight (TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0; // an empty tree is balanced
    }
    int left = balancedHeight(root.left);
    if (left < 0) {
        return -1; // left sub-tree is not balanced, so entire tree is not balanced
    }
    int right = balancedHeight(root.right);
    if (left == right) { // the tree is balanced if both sub-trees are balanced 
                         // and both have same height
        return left + 1;
    } else {
        return -1; // tree is not balanced - either the right sub-tree is not
                   // balanced or the two sub-trees have different heights
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the code I had previously, but the problem is that even if one block evaluates to false, any other recursion that had been set into motion keeps making recursive calls. What I want is that as soon as one recursive instance is set to false, every other instance should stop and return back

Comment: @RahulSaha if `isBalanced(root.left)` evaluates to `false`, `isBalanced(root.right)` won't be called. If `Math.abs(height(root.left)-height(root.right))>1` is `true`, neither `isBalanced(root.left)` nor `isBalanced(root.right)` will be called. I'm not sure what you are concerned about.

Comment: What I was trying to do was to avoid isBalanced(root.left) and isBalanced(root.right) from being invoked completely - by any recursive call in the entire recursive state space - if even one single recursive call found this to be false. So the aim is to not even have to evaluate isBalanced(root.left) if another recursive call evaluated to false.

Comment: @RahulSaha I'm not sure what you mean by that. The first recursive call that returns false will also be the last recursive call that you make, since the false wil propagate to the previous level, which will also return false and so on. That said, please see my suggested improvement.

Comment: Ah you're right! Don't know why I was so confused. Thanks!